# Black screen appears for 80 seconds after windows 10 boot logo and spinning circle! Please help!! :(

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon, hp-pavilion

I have a HP dv6-6b51ea laptop which has AMD Radeon HD 6490M graphics card, and also has the Intel HD Graphics. I recently upgraded my laptop from Windows 7 (64bit) (came with the laptop) to Windows 10 (64bit). When I went to the windows 10 desktop for the the first time after installation, the resolution was unpleasant (1024x720). Suddenly after some hours, the resolution got back to normal (1366x768) . After some time I restarted the laptop, and I saw a new problem. After windows 10 boot logo and spinning circle, a black screen appears for 80 seconds (1 min 20 sec) !!! Then the login screen comes. The problem happens every time I turn on / restart my laptop :(

How can the problem be solved? It's veryy unpleant to wait that long in a fast OS like Windows 10 :(

Please help!!

Comment: Check to ensure you have all the latest device drivers installed.

Comment: i checked. The installed drivers are latest

Comment: You may need to check the programs which are starting with the PC. There may be some delays there as well. Particularly, it may be possible an anti-virus app or other type of system check may be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a laptop that would randomly shut down at any time and wouldn't boot after clicking on the restart button. I was able to track down the culprit in Event Viewer and see what was going on.

Event Viewer will log many things about the boot process, such as the time it took to boot, application errors on boot, etc...

Here is a link to the site that I followed:
http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/use-windows-7-event-viewer-to-track-down-issues-that-cause-slower-boot-times/

This is for Windows 7, but I tested many of the options listed in Windows 10 successfully.

Once you start to use the filter with IDs, you will be able to really narrow down what is causing the slow boots.

Comment: my amd graphics card model is "AMD Radeon HD 6490M'' , but windows 10 detects it as 7400M.  When I uninstall the AMD driver and restart the pc, the delay after boot logo does NOT exist,  BUT the resolution becomes unpleasant (1280x720)  :(

Comment: anyone?? :( help me plse :(

Comment: Open device manager and look for the Display Adapter section.Open the drop down and right click on your driver and try to update the driver from that screen. You may need to download the 6490M driver from the AMD site and try to install that driver to see if it resolves your problem with boot and resolution.